# GCE: Setting Environment Variables from Metadata

Tags: environment-variables, terraform, google-compute-engine, metadata, packer

I am using Packer to generate an image on Google Compute Engine, and Terraform to create the instance. I have set this metadata:

key: `env_vars`

value: `export test=10`

Packer is using a script with something like this inside:

```
curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/attributes/env_vars?recursive=tru&alt=text" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" -o /tmp/env_vars.sh

source /tmp/env_vars.sh # or . /tmp/env_vars.sh
```

The problem is that when I create an instance using this image through Terraform the env variables are not available. That means, If I run `printenv` or `echo $test`, it is empty.

Even if I write a `startup-script` for the instance, it doesn't work.

But, if I run the same exact script inside the instance via SSH, it does work.

In all scenarios described above, the file `env_vars.sh` is created.

I just want to set the env vars from my metadata for any instance.

Any suggestion on how can I achieve this?

EDIT:

Here's the terraform code:

```
# create instance
resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
  count        = 1
  name         = var.machine_name
  machine_type = var.machine_type
  zone         = var.region_zone

  tags = ["allow-http-ssh-rule"]
 
  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = var.source_image
    }
  }
 
  network_interface {
    network = "default"
    access_config {
      // Ephemeral IP
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your terraform code that you are using to create the VM Instance? To take it as a starting point. (please remove any PII information if you are going to share it here)

Comment: Sure! I just updated my post. Does it make sense what I am doing to set the env vars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reproduced your issue in my own project, and you are right it seems that `export`does not work on the strat-up script.

I also tried [creating a start-up script in a bucket](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#cloud-storage) but it does not work.
On the other hand I was able to set the env var in my project:
I’m using a debian-9 image, so, I edited the `/etc/profile` to add the env vars.
I use the following code to create my VM with env variables:

```
provider "google" {
  project = "<<PROJECT-ID>>"
  region  = "us-central1"
  zone    = "us-central1-c"
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "vm_instance" {
  name         = "terraform-instance"
  machine_type = "f1-micro"

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    # A default network is created for all GCP projects
    network = "default"
    access_config {
    }
  }

  # defining metadata
 metadata = {
    foo = "bar"
  }

  metadata_startup_script = "echo  ENVVAR=DEVELOPMENT2 >> /etc/profile"

}
```

After the creation of my instance I was able to see the correct values:

```
$ echo $ENVVAR 
DEVELOPMENT2
```

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what I wanted. It looks like if we want the env vars to persist, they need to be set inside /etc/profile during the startup script. I really appreciate your help and time. Thank you! :)